# Specify which account/user can invoke the API using SAM and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm trying to create an API Gateway which invokes a Lambda function using SAM. I want to restrict access to the API in such a way that only certain IAM accounts/users can access the API. How should I do that? I couldn't find a proper way to attach a resource access policy to an API endpoint in SAM.

Comment: I think what you want is in your `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource, you want to assign a `Role`, which will be an IAM user with the proper permissions.

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an [AWS::Serverless::Api](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessapi) resource in your SAM template that is configured with an [Auth](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api-auth-object) object which in turn should have `AWS_IAM` as `DefaultAuthorizer`. In other words, something like:

```
Resources:

   ApiWithIamAuth:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
```

Next, you need to create a policy for your users so that they can invoke the API. [Control Access for Invoking an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html) provides the reference, [IAM Policy Examples for API Execution Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html) contains two examples

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:a123456789/test/POST/mydemoresource/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and finally [Create and Attach a Policy to an IAM User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-and-attach-iam-policy.html) lists the manual steps to associate the policy with an IAM user, an IAM role or an IAM group.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can limit the access to your APIs using [IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html).

However, SAM supports only a limited number of [resource types](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#resource-types), so you have to use the [IAM Policy type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) of CloudFormation instead.

Since SAM is only a higher-level abstraction of CloudFormation, it is no problem to use native CloudFormation resource types in your SAM template: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/appendix-appendix-sam-templates-and-cf-templates.html